# PortalId for user in Test Class

Tags: portal

In a test class, I have created an updateUser(userId,PortalId,XXX) method.

How to get portal Id for the user created in a test class.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need it.
Salesforce says:

> The portalID value may be null or an empty key if there is no portal configured with this provider.

In the example provided by Salesforce, which I have partially provided here, they don't provide the portal Id:

```
static testMethod void testCreateAndUpdateUser() {
    StandardUserRegistrationHandler handler = new StandardUserRegistrationHandler();
    Auth.UserData sampleData = new Auth.UserData('testId', 'testFirst', 'testLast',
        'testFirst testLast', 'testuser@example.org', null, 'testuserlong', 'en_US', 'facebook',
        null, new Map<String, String>{'language' => 'en_US'});
    User u = handler.createUser(null, sampleData);
    System.assertEquals('testuserlong@salesforce.com', u.userName);
    ///more asserts
    insert(u);
    String uid = u.id;

    sampleData = new Auth.UserData('testNewId', 'testNewFirst', 'testNewLast',
        'testNewFirst testNewLast', 'testnewuser@example.org', null, 'testnewuserlong', 'en_US', 'facebook',
        null, new Map<String, String>{});
    handler.updateUser(uid, null, sampleData);

    User updatedUser = [SELECT userName, email, firstName, lastName, alias FROM user WHERE id=:uid];
    System.assertEquals('testnewuserlong@salesforce.com', updatedUser.userName);
    ///more asserts
}
```

Link to the docs + full code:
[Here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_auth_plugin.htm#apex_Auth_RegistrationHandler_updateUser)